# vagrant up fails with cannot load winrm

Tags: vagrant, winrm

I am trying to run a Vagrant box with SQL Server for local development. I am running Fedora 23. The box in question is [this](http://github.com/mince27/vagrant-mssql-express).

`vagrant up` fails with the following error message:

```
/usr/share/vagrant/plugins/communicators/winrm/shell.rb:9:in `require':
cannot load such file -- winrm (LoadError)
```

I have tried to install `winrm` with `gem install winrm`, and it installs just fine, but vagrant still fails.

The following ruby script runs without errors:

```
require "winrm"
puts "hello world"
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: your problem in fact is winrm install. What is your error when to try to install winrm ?

Comment: winrm installs just fine. I've updated the question with more info.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was, but I fixed it by uninstalling vagrant with dnf, and installing the latest version from vagrantup.com. Seems winrm is included in the latest vagrant version.

Comment: This was the easiest solution for me.  Just `sudo apt remove vagrant` followed by a download and install of the latest .deb from the vagrantup.

Answer (score 28):

The winrm and winrm-fs gems are not packaged with Fedora or Debian. You can run:

```
$ vagrant plugin install winrm
$ vagrant plugin install winrm-fs
```

(i.e. vagrant plugin install, not gem install).

**Note: Using Vagrant version `1.8.1`, the `winrm` gem failed to install and this fixed it:**

```
$ vagrant plugin install winrm --plugin-version 1.8.1
$ vagrant plugin install winrm-fs
```

Answer (score 21):

Had the same issue:
With Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS running ruby 2.7.0p0 and Vagrant 2.2.6

The solution that worked for me -

```
$ vagrant plugin install winrm  
$ vagrant plugin install winrm-fs  
$ vagrant plugin install winrm-elevated (this additional error showed after the first two were installed)
```

Comment: It worked from me with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS as host. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Same resolution as here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/mBYMUHm-YBI

> So this is an issue with the Debian packaged version of Vagrant. Installing the DEB package from https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html works (both for 1.6.5 and 1.7+).
>
> [780036](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=780036) has been raised with Debian to track this issue.

Comment: This was the easiest solution for Debian 8 (Jessie), which throws errors (zlib, Ruby version...) if I try to do vagrant plugin install winrm...